# How to make a call and response with Peerjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, peerjs

Is there a way to use the peerjs dataconnection channel as a call and response message channel? For example I send information from peer1 to peer2. On the peer1 side I wait for a specific response. If peer2 sends back a specific response, then peer1 does something. How would I do that?

I tried registering a new listener when sending information, or already having a listener for responses. Both solutions are pretty ugly. I'd like to wrap it into smth like a promised based thing e.g: send(Param).then(//Stuff)